# PHP find url in sa text and save in array

Tags: php

I have a txt file and I want to save in array all the urls starting from http:// and ends with .png or .jpg or .jpeg. How can I do that?

Can I use this?

```
<?php
function getUrls($string)
{
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}

$urls = getUrls($string);

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    echo $url.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you showed will not work because there's nothing specifying `.png`, `.jpg`, or `.jpeg` in the regex. It will also only return the first match: `$matches[0]`. Additionally, it needs `/g` flag to find multiple instances in the same string (`/i` just ignores case).

Try this instead:

```
<?php
function getUrls($string)
{
    // \w is any word character
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[\w]+\.(jpg|png|jpeg)/ig';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches);
}

$urls = getUrls($string);

foreach($urls as $url)
{
    echo $url.'<br />';
}
?>
```